# При использование VK.Api.call('widgets.getComments') данные возвращаються только если авторизован в VK

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

Хочу вывести количество комментариев у поста, с помощью метода

```
VK.Api.call('widgets.getComments', {widget_api_id: apiId, url: url},   function (obj) {
    console.log(obj.response.count);
});
```

Но данные возвращаются только если я авторизован в браузере в vk.com.
Как можно получить количество комментариев без авторизации в социальном сервисе?

Comment: Решили проблему? Если да, то поделитесь решением, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Алекс к сожалению это было так давно, что уже не помню